# image binary classification using Transfer learning (Dense layers with 1 or 2 Node)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, tf.keras

I want to make a prediction with 2 classes, image binary classification.
I want to use MobileNet (transfer learning) as my algorithm, to compare trainable = True or False.

My questions are :

1. I tried to compare the last layer (Dense) with 1 or 2 nodes,

A. with 2 nodes, softmax (sigmoid will be Error)

```
num_classes = 2
model_mobilenet = tf.keras.Sequential([feature_extractor_layer,
                              tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation = 'softmax') ])
    
model_mobilenet.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),loss=tensorflow.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

compare to another code with 1 node sigmoid activation function :

```
model_mobilenet2 = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_extractor_layer,
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')
])

model_mobilenet2.compile(
  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
  loss=tensorflow.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
  metrics=['accuracy'])

history_mobilenet2 = model_mobilenet2.fit(train_img, 
                    train_lab, 
                    epochs=50, 
                    validation_data=(test_img, test_lab), 
                    callbacks=[callback],
                    verbose = 2)
```

With those 2 code has same results. Any idea why it happened?

B. My 2nd question is based on previous code, if i am using 1 node in Dense layer with sigmoid, and i change from logits=False, it will be Error.
Any idea why it happened?

Thank you

deep knowledge and try to know for the improvements